# Invoke another 'play' based on output of another play - Ansible

Tags: ansible, selinux

I am trying to use `Ansible` to check if `SELinux` is enabled (set to Enforcing), and if not, enable it. The `play` to enable `SELinux` must be invoked only if `SELinux` is disabled.

The `playbook` looks like so:

```
- hosts: all

  # root should execute this.
  remote_user: root
  become: yes

  tasks:

    # Check if SELinux is enabled.
    - name: check if selinux is enabled
      tags: selinuxCheck
      register: selinuxCheckOut
      command: getenforce
    - debug: var=selinuxCheckOut.stdout_lines

    - name: enable selinux if not enabled already
      tags: enableSELinux
      selinux: policy=targeted state=enforcing
      when: selinuxCheckOut.stdout_lines == "Enforcing"
    - debug: var=enableSELinuxOut.stdout_lines
```

When I run this, the task `enableSELinux` fails with the reason, "Conditional check failed". The output is:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
task path: /root/ansible/playbooks/selinuxConfig.yml:24
ok: [localhost] => {
    "selinuxCheckOut.stdout_lines": [
        "Enforcing"
    ]
}

TASK [enable selinux if not enabled already] ***********************************
task path: /root/ansible/playbooks/selinuxConfig.yml:26
skipping: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed", "skipped": true}
```

My questions:
1. Is this the correct way to get a play to execute depending on the output from another play?
2. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your playbook is correct. But `stdout_lines` is a list. You have to compare the first element in that list. Try this:

```
when: selinuxCheckOut.stdout_lines[0] == "Enforcing"
```